# AWS Glue Crawler overwrite custom table properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a data catalog managed by AWS Glue, and any update that my developers does in our S3 bucket with new tables or partitions we are using the crawlers to update that every day to keep the new partitions healthy.

But, we also need custom table properties. In our hive we have the data source of each table as a table property, and we added to the tables in the Data Catalog in glue but, every time we run the crawler it overwrites the custom table properties like Description.

Am I doing anything wrong? Or is this a bug from AWS Glue?

Comment: Hey, facing the same problem, did you resolve it?

Comment: Sorry, not solved yet :(

Comment: Same here, did you by chance figure it out? Thanks

Comment: Not yet Mate, We had a work around in the company structure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `Schema change policy` in your crawler definition?

[image]

Comment: This will not help - this will stop the update of the schema, while the problem he's facing is with the crawler wiping the custom table properties